# How to share data across routed components in Vue.js using webpack?

Tags: vue.js

So I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use the `vue-loader` for Webpack, `vue-router` for routes, and how to have a shared data model. My understanding is that you create a data model, and then pass it into each component with the idea that they have a shared state. It also seems that you should use the data model rather than props, as that allows for two-way binding.

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work. I tried passing the `data` through in the router, but that doesn't fix it.

I have this as my main `app.js`:

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    Vue = require('vue'),
    VueRouter = require('vue-router');

Vue.use(VueRouter);

var first = require('vue!./first.vue');
var second = require('vue!./second.vue');

var sourceOfTruth = {
    msg: "my message"
};

var App = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth,
});

var router = new VueRouter({
    history: true
});

router.map({
    '/foo': {
        data: sourceOfTruth,
        component: first
    },
    '/bar': {
        data: sourceOfTruth,
        component: second
    }
});

router.start(App, '#app');
```

And this as my `first.vue`:

```
<template>
    The message goes here -> {{ msg }}
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // ???
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `require('vue!./second.vue');` Mind to explain what it does? I mean the part before the dot.

Comment: @YauheniPrakopchyk I assume thats how you require things using webpack.

Comment: @notANerdDev thanks for explanation.

Comment: @notANerdDev is correct - it forces webpack to load the file using `vue-loader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom data fields that are sent through are not accessed like component data fields. You are trying `{{ msg }}`, this would look for a `msg` field in your component.

To access the data sent via router,

`{{ $route.data }}`

Now, since in your case, data is in turn json, you would do

`{{ $route.data.msg }}`

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://skyronic.com/2016/01/03/vuex-basics-tutorial/) very good article which deals with communication between independent components. It is also an introduction to the `Flux` way of thinking with [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex). Generally speaking you should be ok with a shared store instance, where you import it it every component from a separate file and make it reactive by assigning to each component's data.

```
<template>
    {{ sourceOfTruth.msg }}
</template>

<script>
    import store from '../store'

    export default {
       data () {
          return {
            sourceOfTruth : store.sourceOfTruth 
         }
      } 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That article is really helpful, and Vuex seems to be very promising.