# Vuejs Share Data Between Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components:

- App.vue
- Sidekick.vue

In my `App.vue` component, I have a property that I would like to access from `Sidekick.vue`

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ myData }}</p>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <router-view/> // our sidekick component is shown here
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      myData: 'is just this string'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Sidekick.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="sidekick">
    {{ myData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Sidekick'
}
</script>
```

I would like access to `myData` (which is declared in `App.vue`) from `Sidekick.vue`

I have tried importing `App.vue` from within `Sidekick.vue` by doing something like:

**Sidekick.vue** *(incorrect attempt)*

```
<script>
import App from '@/App'
export default {
  name: 'Sidekick',
  data () {
    return {
      myData: App.myData
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have read about props - but have only seen references to child / parent components. In my case, `Sidekick.vue` is shown in a div inside `App.vue` (not sure if this makes it a "child"). Do I need to give access of `myData` to `<router-view/>` somehow?

**UPDATE: (to show relationship between App.vue and Sidekick.vue**

**index.js** *(router file)*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Sidekick from '@/components/Sidekick',
import FakeComponent from '@/components/FakeComponent'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/fakecomponent'
    },
    {
      path: '/sidekick',
      name: 'Sidekick',
      component: Sidekick
    },
    {
      path: '/fakecomponent',
      name: 'FakeComponent',
      component: FakeComponent
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

`Sidekick.vue` gets rendered when we hit `/sidekick`

Comment: "Sidekick.vue is shown in a div inside App.vue" where is your Sidekick used i can't see them on App's template besides route-view, i assume `props` is the right way to go just want some more context :)

Comment: With data being shared from parent to child, you should consider using props. If you have multiple nested components and you're passing the same prop values between all of them, or you're trying to share data from child to parent or between siblings reactively, you might want to consider looking into `Vuex`. I personally don't use Vuex myself, but I don't currently deal with complex enough Vue applications to warrant its use. Since you appear to be developing an SPA, you may find some benefit in using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590160/how-to-share-data-between-components-vue-js)

Comment: @Xlee I have updated the original question with the relationship between "App" and "Sidekick"

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607194/how-to-share-data-across-routed-components-in-vue-js-using-webpack

Comment: not quality code but you can also use `{{ $root.myData }}` as a quick fix i believe, the correct way would be props, an event bus or vuex

Comment: Thanks @keja , I don't mind the quick and dirty solution, but couldn't get any results from `$root`

Comment: Okay, i guess your app.vue is a child then, so you would have to do `{{ $root.$children[0].myData }}` or something like that. you could find it if you log the $root to the console `console.log(this.$root)` or `console.log(this.$root.$children)` not pretty but should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just keep in mind, the rule of thumb is using props to pass data in a one-way flow

> props down, events up.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

**Quick solution:**

Global event bus to post messages between your `<App/>` and `<Sidekick/>` components.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

**Long term solution**:

Use a state management library like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) to better encapsulates data in one place (a global store) and subscribe it from your components tree using `import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'`

Answer (score 5):

> When you have parent-child communication, the best and recommended
> option is to use props and events. [Read more in Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

---

> When want to have shared state between many components the best and
> recommended way is to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org).

---

If you want to use simple data sharing you can use [Vue observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable).

**Simple example:** Say that you have a game and you want the errors to be accessible by many components. (components can access it and manipulate it).

***errors.js***

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const errors = Vue.observable({ count: 0 });
```

***Component1.vue***

```
import { errors } from 'path-of-errors.js'

export default {
  computed: {
    errors () {
      get () { return errors.count },
      set (val) { errors.count = val }
    }
  }
}
```

In `Component1` the `errors.count` is reactive. So if as a template you have:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Errors: {{ errors }} 
    <button @click="errors++">Increase</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

While you click the *Increase* button, you will see the errors increasing.

---

As you might expect, when you import the `errors.js` in another component, then both components can participate on manipulating the `errors.count`.

---

**Note:** Even though you might use the Vue.observable API for simple data sharing you should be aware that this is a very powerful API. For example read [Using Vue Observables as a State Store](https://dev.to/cooperaustinj/using-vue-observable-as-a-state-store-37fa)

Answer (score 2):

*App.vue:*

---

```
<router-view pass_data='myData'/>
```

*Sidekick.vue:*

---

```
export default {
  name: "Sidekick",
  props: ["pass_data"],
  created() {
    alert("pass_data: "+this.pass_data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***If App.js(Parent) and Sidekick(Child)***

***App.js***

in Template

In script
import Sidekick from './Sidekick.vue:

***Sidekick.vue***

props: ['myData']

> now you can access myData anywhere in sidekick.
> In template myData and
> in scripts this.myData