# How to pass data between components in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a page with many help buttons.

When a button is clicked I get with axios the help, returned as json (component vue-ob-button-help)

How can I update a help div (component vue-ob-help) with the return value and slide it down

How can I pass data from vue-ob-button-help to vue-ob-help ?

so far I have in a page.php

```html
 ...
<vue-ob-button-help help-id=12></vue-ob-button-help>
<vue-ob-help help-id=12"></div>
...
<vue-ob-button-help help-id=25></vue-ob-button-help>
<vue-ob-help help-id=25></div>
```

and in js .

```js
      Vue.component('vue-ob-help', {
            props: ['helpId'],
            methods: {},
            template: '<div class="help-block"></div>'
        });

     Vue.component('vue-ob-button-help', {
                props: ['helpId'],
                methods: {
                    getHelp: function (event) {
                        var e = event.currentTarget;
                        var id = this.helpId;
                        axios.get("/a_help/help?id=" + this.helpId)
                            .then(function (r) {
                                if (r.data.label) {
                                    if (r.data.linkUpdate) {
                                        r.data.label = '<a href="' + r.data.linkUpdate + '" class="float-right ob-btn-link mr-3"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>' + r.data.label;
                                    }
                                    r.data.label = '<button class="close" type="button">×</button>' + r.data.label;

                                    // this is what is working with Jquery and I want to change it to vue
                                    //
                                    // var target = '#help_' + this.helpId;
                                    // $(target).html(r.label).slideDown();
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(function (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    }
                },
                template: '<button type="button" v-on:click="getHelp($event)">help</button>'
            });
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511203/8191362

Comment: You could use props or vuex if you have many data you want to pass/update:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/