# How to throw data to main App.vue from views?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a simple Vue application with this structure:

```
App -> router -> [view1, view2, view3 ...]
```

**I want to throw `token` from `GameStart` to `App`**. How to do it? I have tried to use `this.$emit` but this isn't work. I think it's beacause vue-router is parent for GameStart.

Should I use `Vuex` for this problem or there is another way to do it?

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content transition="slide-x-transition">
      <router-view></router-view>
      token:{{token}}
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    token: "",
  }),
  }
};
</script>
```

*router/index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/game-start/',
    name: 'game-start',
    component: () => import('../views/GameStart.vue')
  }
];
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

*GameStart.vue*

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'gamestart',
  data: () => ({
    token: "",
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `this.$root.$emit('message')` to send a message to root and `this.$on()` in the root component to listen.

Comment: @JesusGalvan this is a good idea, but is that a 'true' method for data sharing?

Comment: No, this is not a good solution for state management. Vuex is your answer if you want a more reliable state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs Share Data Between Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510511/vuejs-share-data-between-components)